# How to convert model to string in controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

When I return a GUID from a controller action in ASP.NET, I get a string back:

```cs
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    // returns `"544b4406-9cb8-4c4f-8ea2-bc535b0d3888"`
    [HttpGet]
    public Guid Get() => Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

This works even for complex models:

```cs
public class MyModel {
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}

public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    // returns `{ id: "544b4406-9cb8-4c4f-8ea2-bc535b0d3888" }`
    [HttpGet]
    public MyModel Get() => new MyModel();
}
```

How can I get a custom `MyId` class to be returned as string as well?

```cs
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    // returns `{}`
    [HttpGet]
    public MyId Get() => MyId.NewId();
}
```

Comment: What does your `MyId` class look like?

Comment: @KlausGütter it's quite basic, something along the lines of `[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MyIdModelBinder))] public class MyId : IEquatable<MyId>, IEquatable<string> { private readonly string id; }`. I've used https://github.com/visus-io/cuid.net/blob/main/src/cuid.net/Cuid2.cs as a starting point but it's not a Cuid2.

Comment: Why don't you [edit] your question and show it?

Comment: Because I'm not allowed to post the full class - client confidentiality, unfortunately. Moreover, I believe the question should be possible to answer without the full id class.

Comment: In the case of incoming models, it seems we can use `ModelBinder`, for outgoing models, the closest approximation I've found is `ActionFilter` but I have not been able to find an example which is general enough to work similarly to Guid.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was: Use a custom `JsonConverter`:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyIdJsonConverter))]
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MyIdModelBinder))]
[SwaggerSchemaFilter(typeof(MyIdSchemaFilter))]
public class MyId : IEquatable<MyId>, IEquatable<string> {
    private readonly string id;
}

public class MyIdJsonConverter : JsonConverter<MyId>
{
    public override MyId? Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options
    ) => // e.g. MyId.Parse(reader.GetString());

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        MyId value,
        JsonSerializerOptions options
    ) => // e.g. writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `MyId` does not have any public properties. Therefore, the serialization result is empty.
You need to write your own `JsonConverter` for `MyId` type.